# Serial behaviour based on tags in an Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I run a playbook, which contains a role, and executes so it runs once against the first server in the host file, it then executes against 25% of servers in the host file, finally, it executes against the rest of the servers.

What I want to achieve is:

- If I run the playbook without any tags or `task1`, it should run against all servers in one go.
- If I run the playbook with tags `task2` it runs the playbook in batches (as per the `serial`).

At the moment, it will always run in batches regardless.

I have the following playbooks:

Playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  serial:
    - 1
    - "25%"
    - "100%"

  roles:
    - playbook2
```

*playbook2* role:

```yaml
- name: task 1
  shell: [do something]
  tags: task1

- name: task 2
  shell: [do more]
  tags: task2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can template `serial` and [`omit`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#making-variables-optional) it based on the content of the tags, and the [special variable `ansible_run_tags`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html).

Your `serial` parameter, then should be

```yaml
serial: "{{ ['1', '25%', '100%'] if 'task2' in ansible_run_tags else omit }}"
```

---

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: _nodes
  gather_facts: no
  serial: "{{ ['1', '25%', '100%'] if 'task2' in ansible_run_tags else omit }}"

  tasks:
    - debug:
      tags:
        - task2

    - debug:
      tags:
        - task2
```

When run with no tags, on three hosts it will yield:

```
PLAY [_nodes] ***********************************************************

TASK [debug] ************************************************************
ok: [node2] => 
  msg: Hello world!
ok: [node3] => 
  msg: Hello world!
ok: [node1] => 
  msg: Hello world!

TASK [debug] ************************************************************
ok: [node2] => 
  msg: Hello world!
ok: [node3] => 
  msg: Hello world!
ok: [node1] => 
  msg: Hello world!
```

When run with `--tags task2`, it will, then, yield:

```
PLAY [_nodes] ***********************************************************

TASK [debug] ************************************************************
ok: [node2] => 
  msg: Hello world!

TASK [debug] ************************************************************
ok: [node2] => 
  msg: Hello world!

PLAY [_nodes] ***********************************************************

TASK [debug] ************************************************************
ok: [node3] => 
  msg: Hello world!

TASK [debug] ************************************************************
ok: [node3] => 
  msg: Hello world!

PLAY [_nodes] ***********************************************************

TASK [debug] ************************************************************
ok: [node1] => 
  msg: Hello world!

TASK [debug] ************************************************************
ok: [node1] => 
  msg: Hello world!
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you. (Unable to upvote due to rep but makes it as accepted answer).

Actually, I noticed you actually edited my question to make more sense. I was unsure how to actually describe what I wanted. So thanks again!